# How can I get sudo to authorize me on multiple pty's with one password?

Tags: sudo, debian-squeeze

I'm running `sudo` version 1.7.4 on Debian squeeze.  In this version, unlike some older versions, every pty has to be authorized separately with a password and timeout.  In older versions, one password was good for *any* pty during the timeout period.  I'd like to persuade `sudo` to revert to that older behavior, so that I can use a bunch of xterm windows without having to retype my password continually.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at the tty_tickets option

From the man page

> tty_tickets
>
> If set, users must authenticate on a per-tty basis. With this flag enabled, sudo will >use a file named for the tty the user is logged in on in the user's time stamp directory. If >disabled, the time stamp of the directory is used instead. This flag is on by default

To disable this behaviour set

```
Defaults ! tty_tickets
```

in your `sudoers` file.

Comment: Exactly what I needed.  Just couldn't find that option amongst the 50 other options available.  Thank you!